# Testing Exception in Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit

I have the following exception that I am trying to test

```
     public void Land(Plane plane)
        {
            if (weather.Forecast() != "stormy")
            {
                planes.Add(plane);
                Console.WriteLine($"{ plane.Name } has landed at {_AirportName}");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("It's too stormy to land");
            }
        }
```

However I can't seem to find the right syntax to test this exception? From searching around, I so far have:

```
Assert.Throws(Is.TypeOf<Exception>())
                 .And.Message.EqualTo("Too stormy to land");
```

However it says that Throws can't be inferred from the usage.

Can anyone help? (Sorry, very new to C#!)
Thanks :)

Comment: The linked duplicate is very old, so this is the modern syntax: `var exception = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => foo.Land(plane));
   Assert.AreEqual(exception.Message, "It's too stormy to land");`

Comment: Thank you @stuartd I appreciate your help! However, the test does not pass, it simply shows me the Exception?

Comment: This test passes - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmVfe.png

Comment: Ah I see thank you! My mistake - I had foo.Land(plane) written above and had forgotten to delete it.